# Running a CGI script in my browser WAMP

Tags: html, cgi

I am trying to run the basic cgi script to generate some html and I am just getting the raw code, here is the general script.  Is there something else I have to set, I am on a windows system.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
 print <<HTML;
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>A Simple Perl CGI</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>A Simple Perl CGI</h1>
 <p>Hello World</p>
 </body>
 HTML
 exit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow the tutorial here: http://chromicdesign.com/2009/05/setting-up-perl-for-wampp.html

Hopefully you'll be up and running in the end.

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you, some of the documentation regarding this topic is just all over the place, I will start reading something and realize it's unix.

Comment: the installation commands, sorry I meant in Linux.  I was reading one thing and following along and realized it was talking about terminal commands to enter, I was having issues finding wamp documantation.

Comment: I am not sure what are you saying. But i think your question is about getting cgi up and running in windows system, right? Well, the blog post is for windows only. To run the command in window, you use command prompt, you can open it by `win+r` then type `cmd` and then press `Enter`.